# Confusions of or in?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I am not sure which of the following sentences sounds more natural/correct.

> Confusions of my head are driving me crazy

**Or**

> Confusions in my head are driving me crazy

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I am trying this as a sentence in a song lyric. I want to say that my head is filled with confusions and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Please provide at least one complete sentence for context.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my post to put some context. The text that I have added is not a part of song lyric, so not sure if that's helpful enough, but unfortunately I don't have any other sentence here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention wanting this to be a song lyric. That allows for more freedom with grammar and style than does formal (or even informal) writing.

Using *of* is often the same thing as a possessive, and *in* can often be rephrased as *inside*.

This means you could compare the following two meanings:

> My head's confusions are driving me crazy.
>   Confusions inside my head are driving me crazy.

---

Of course, you could paraphrase these things in different ways—but it would also subtly alter their meaning:

> Confusing thoughts are driving me crazy.
>   Internal confusions are driving me crazy.

---

I personally think that *confusions* ***of*** *my head* is the least natural sounding. But I wouldn't necessarily choose *confusions* ***in*** *my head* either.

In the end, it's based on what you want to convey, how it works in the context of the other lyrics, and your own preference.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I will choose "of" without any concern then for this lyric that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have confusions of the foot or confusions of the elbow, you don't really need to say "of the head". And we normally refer to it in the singular:

> Confusion is driving me crazy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, I have to disagree with it. The reason why it would be logical to use "confusion/s of the head", at the least from a lyrical standpoint, is because confusions arise in head/mind only. Other parts of the body don't have thinking power, so naturally the word won't suit and cannot be used with such parts.

Comment: @LoveEnigma. You sound confused.

Comment: @LoveEnigma: You can say anything you like in a lyric. But if you want it to sound natural in English, "confusions of my head" is not the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps your answer confused me. Yes, I understand your point. I will see what I can do best with what I have.